# searching for regex word boundery with partial and complete words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$str = 'Company Name Internal Transport Worldwide  
Account Manager New Business';

I tried:
$re = "/\b(internal.transport|accountmanag|account.manag).*\W/mi";  
// result: Internal Transport 

$re = "/\b(internal.transport|accountmanag|account.manag)\w+/mi";  
// result: Account Manager

$re = "/\b(internal.transport|accountmanag.`*|account.manag.`*)\W/mi";  
// result: Internal Transport, Account Manager New

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

I'm looking for this result:
- Internal Transport
- Account Manager

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: found something, this seems to work:   "/\b(internal.transport|accountmanag|account.manag)\w*/mi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~\b(?:internal\Wtransport|accountmanag|account\Wmanag)\w*~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I8QL0L/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:internal\Wtransport|accountmanag|account\Wmanag)` - a non-capturing alternation group matching any of the three alternatives:

  - `internal\Wtransport`  - `internal`, a non-word char, `transport`
  - `|`  - or
  - `accountmanag` - `accountmanag`
  - `|` - or
  - `account\Wmanag` - `account`, a non-word char, `manag`
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/QsTJ9t):

```
$str = 'Company Name Internal Transport Worldwide  
Account Manager New Business';

$re = "/\b(?:internal\Wtransport|accountmanag|account\Wmanag)\w*/i";  
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Internal Transport
    [1] => Account Manager
)
```